# Basic Python Dictionary of String Keys and Int Values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm writing a very basic script that calculates an NFL player's fantasy football points based on last year's full-season data.  When I do this, I look at the number of games they will miss this year, and apply that discount factor to their total points.

E.g. Tom Brady will miss 4 games this year so he loses 25% of his points.

Since so few players are going to miss games, I have a dictionary that maps a player's name to the number of games he'll miss.  When I create players, I check whether his name is in the `SUSPENSIONS` dictionary like so:

```
if name in SUSPENSIONS.keys():
    newTE = TE(name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles, receptionYards, receptionTouchdowns, SUSPENSIONS[name])
```

I tested this with Antonio Gates, who's going to miss 4 games this year.  His discount of 25% isn't being applied.  I run the above code and then do:

```
print(str(newTE.gamesSuspended))
```

and get back 0.

Here's my `SUSPENSIONS` dictionary:

```
SUSPENSIONS = {"Antonio Gates": 4, "Ahmad Bradshaw": 1, "Trey Watts": 4, "Tom Brady": 4, "Josh Gordon": 16, "Le'Veon Bell": 2, "LeGarrette Blount": 1}
```

A few interesting things:

1) Tom Brady's discount *does* get applied although Le'Veon Bell's, Antonio Gates, and presumably most others don't.

2) My code knows that "Antonio Gates" is a key in the `SUSPENSIONS` dictionary.  For some reason, it sets his `gamesSuspended` field to 0 instead of 4 (the value corresponding to his name in the dictionary).  Why is this?

Any help in sorting this out would be much appreciated,
bclayman

Edit to show TE.py:

```
from Player import *
from constants import *

class TE(Player):
    def __init__(self, name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles, receptionYards, receptionTouchdowns, position="TE", gamesSuspended=0):
        super().__init__(name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles, gamesSuspended)
        self.receptionYards = receptionYards
        self.receptionTouchdowns = receptionTouchdowns
        self.position = "TE"

    def calculatePoints(self):
        return (super().calculatePercentageOfSeason() * (super().calculatePoints() + POINTS_PER_RECEPTION_YARD * self.receptionYards + POINTS_PER_RECEPTION_TOUCHDOWN * self.receptionTouchdowns))

    def toString(self):
        return "position: " + self.position + " " + super().toString() + " rushing yards: " + str(self.rushingYards) + " rushing touchdowns: " + str(self.rushingTouchdowns) + " rushing fumbles: " + st    r(self.rushingFumbles) + " reception yards: " + str(self.receptionYards) + " reception touchdowns: " + str(self.receptionTouchdowns)
```

So `TE(...)` is a constructor the Tight End class.  If `gamesSuspended` variable doesn't get bound, it's initialized to 0 (since it's an optional parameter).  But I do pass in `gamesSuspended`...

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo, but your code says `SUSPENSION[name]`, instead of `SUSPENSIONS[name]`.

Comment: @AnthonyHilyard Just a typo, thanks tho

Comment: You haven't given enough context. You seem to refer to a function `TE()` which presumably has the bug. What is this function?

Comment: You better have a suspensions Dictionary just for the Cowboys. They legitimately can be called the chain gang.

Comment: @JohnColeman Just edited to include TE.py file and explained what the function does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the `gamesSuspended` for the player's *position*, which I don't think you want.

With so many parameters in the contructor, sometimes it is useful to use named parameters as to not get them mixed up.

```
newTE = TE(name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles, receptionYards,
           receptionTouchdowns, position="TE", gamesSuspended=SUSPENSIONS[name])
```

Comment: No problem! Getting into the habit of named parameters makes the code much more readable and helps to avoid mistakes.